# Electron-builder makes not workable packages (ubuntu)

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm working with Ubuntu 18.04 and making builds using electron-builder (node.js, react application). Finally I have workable building which makes some zips (win and linux) and deb (linux). When I install the deb, it works well, but when I unzip the builds, I can't run them:

1. windows version doesn't work via wine
2. linux version is not executable.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, electron 4.0.4, electron-builder 20.38.5.

Here is my `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "dist": "electron-builder --linux --windows",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
},
"build": {
    "appId": "my_app_id",
    "extraFiles": [
        "assets"
    ],
    "win": {
        "target": "zip",
        "icon": "assets/icon.png"
    },
    "linux": {
        "target": [
            "deb",
            "zip"
        ],
        "icon": "assets/icon.icns"
    }
}
```

So, first I run **npx webpack** to build the app. Then I run **npm run dist** to make the builds. It creates linux-x64.zip, win32-x64.zip, amd64.deb. But the thing inside the zips doesn't work.

One important note: I got this stuff as a heritage from other developer, and maybe he didn't commit something necessary and maybe all of this staff was just his training solution and doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem has gone. I don't need the linux zip, deb works fine. And windows zip works well (tested via VirtualBox).

Comment: Can you say what fixed it?